# 802.11s mesh_params documentation

Tags: linux, openwrt, wireless-bridge, 802.11, mesh-networking

I have connected 2 devices using an 802.11s mesh for Layer 2 bridging.
The first device is turned on most of the times, but the second one isn't. So, I am looking for a way to reduce the scanning frequency/interval of the first device in searching for mesh peers when disconnected. But I'm not sure how to achieve the same.

Below is the list of mesh parameters supported on my device from the output of `iw dev wlan1 get mesh_param`:

```
mesh_retry_timeout
mesh_confirm_timeout
mesh_holding_timeout
mesh_max_peer_links
mesh_max_retries
mesh_ttl
mesh_element_ttl
mesh_auto_open_plinks
mesh_hwmp_max_preq_retries
mesh_path_refresh_time
mesh_min_discovery_timeout
mesh_hwmp_active_path_timeout
mesh_hwmp_preq_min_interval
mesh_hwmp_net_diameter_traversal_time
mesh_hwmp_rootmode
mesh_hwmp_rann_interval
mesh_gate_announcements
mesh_fwding
mesh_sync_offset_max_neighor
mesh_rssi_threshold
mesh_hwmp_active_path_to_root_timeout
mesh_hwmp_root_interval
mesh_hwmp_confirmation_interval
mesh_power_mode
mesh_awake_window
mesh_plink_timeout
mesh_connected_to_gate
mesh_nolearn
mesh_connected_to_as
```

I could not find the documentation for any of the above mesh parameters. I have referred to the [Kernel wiki for 802.11s](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/ieee80211/802.11s), but it doesn't have any description about the above parameters.
I did find out about what certain parameters do, from the [open80211s HOWTO](https://github.com/o11s/open80211s/wiki/HOWTO) (that was linked in the [Kernel wiki for `iw`](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw#creating_and_inspecting_mesh_point_interfaces_with_iw)) but it doesn't have a description of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

For meanings of mesh parameters, here are some places to check:

1. enum `nl80211_meshconf_params` and its comments, in `nl80211.h`, iw source.
2. struct `mesh_param_descr` `_mesh_param_descrs[]` definition, in `mesh.c`, iw source. This shows how user settings map to internal parameters.
3. struct `mesh_config` and its comments, in `include/net/cfg80211.h`, Linux source.
4. enum `ieee80211_root_mode_identifier` and its comments, in `include/linux/ieee80211.h`, Linux source.
5. IEEE Std 802.11 PDF, freely available from the Internet. Latest ver `802.11-2016.pdf`.

E.g. root mode explained:

```c
/* FILE: include/linux/ieee80211.h, Linux source */

/**
 * enum ieee80211_root_mode_identifier - root mesh STA mode identifier
 *
 * These attribute are used by dot11MeshHWMPRootMode to set root mesh STA mode
 *
 * @IEEE80211_ROOTMODE_NO_ROOT: the mesh STA is not a root mesh STA (default)
 * @IEEE80211_ROOTMODE_ROOT: the mesh STA is a root mesh STA if greater than
 *  this value
 * @IEEE80211_PROACTIVE_PREQ_NO_PREP: the mesh STA is a root mesh STA supports
 *  the proactive PREQ with proactive PREP subfield set to 0
 * @IEEE80211_PROACTIVE_PREQ_WITH_PREP: the mesh STA is a root mesh STA
 *  supports the proactive PREQ with proactive PREP subfield set to 1
 * @IEEE80211_PROACTIVE_RANN: the mesh STA is a root mesh STA supports
 *  the proactive RANN
 */
enum ieee80211_root_mode_identifier {
    IEEE80211_ROOTMODE_NO_ROOT = 0,
    IEEE80211_ROOTMODE_ROOT = 1,
    IEEE80211_PROACTIVE_PREQ_NO_PREP = 2,
    IEEE80211_PROACTIVE_PREQ_WITH_PREP = 3,
    IEEE80211_PROACTIVE_RANN = 4,
};
```

If you are using `mesh11sd`, use `mesh11sd status` to check for current settings, this command invokes iw, so you can also use iw directly.

Put any mesh parameters in `mesh11sd` config file and save, they will be set effective by `mesh11sd`, no reload needed.

E.g. to reduce traffic, on root/main node:

```
/etc/config/mesh11sd

config mesh11sd 'mesh_params'
    option mesh_hwmp_rootmode '4'
    option mesh_hwmp_rann_interval '8000'
```

On occasionally-on node:

```
config mesh11sd 'mesh_params'
    option mesh_hwmp_rootmode '0'
```